# How to make query more efficient ? using ORACLE DB and C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I was trying to upload data from excel , if exist then update else insert ,
this query is working but when i am sending bulk data like 50000+ data it is taking too much time and program not working , please help some efficient way

```
 string query = @"BEGIN ";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string DATA = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string DATA = row.Cells[1].Text;
            string DATA = row.Cells[2].Text;//from drop down
            string DATA = row.Cells[3].Text;//from drop down

            query += @"DECLARE
   CNT   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT  Query;

   IF CNT = 0
   THEN
      INSERT Query;
   ELSE
      UPDATE  Query;
   END IF;
END;";

        }
        query += "END;";
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
```

Answer: I tried creating a demo table the same as the master table and do insert, then made a procedure to merge both tables to one. And it worked perfectly.

Comment: Are your records mostly new or mostly updates?

Comment: Sir mostly insert but after some month it will be mostly update . So i will say its 50 50.

Comment: Have you ever heard about [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/)?

Comment: If it's 50/50 I'd say "load them all into a temp table and use a merge statement". If it was highly new I would say "do an insert, catch a crash due to primary key violation and do an update". If it was highly existing I would say "do an update, if it affects 0 records, do an insert"

Comment: Look at your code like trying to save 50000+ data with only one transaction,it can’t be fast.Try one transaction per each data.I did the same job,and i finish it used this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about c#/oracle, but if it is in the same session, you can mayby:

-create a package

-define a collection there

-in this loop fill this collection

-after loop run another block which runs merge statement (if matched update if not insert)